# can Powershell on Google Cloud manage LINUX instance?

Tags: powershell, gcloud

Just to have 100% clarity, does the announcement https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/09/running-Powershell-on-Google-Cloud-SDK.html mean that PowerShell can be used to manage Google Cloud resources/instances independent of the actually installed operating system (i.e. Linux OS)?﻿

Comment: For questions Google links to stackoverflow in the referenced article :(
'Got questions? Let us know.'

Comment: Right... I forgot SO is Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** The PowerShell cmdlets are a wrapper for `gcloud`, which is a cross-platform CLI for managing Google Cloud Platform resources.